# How do I return an Array from asyncData in nuxt from firestore for SSR?

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am attempting to get my app to render my data in an array from Firestore in SSR using asyncData. My function outside of asyncData is working fine but I can NOT get it to work inside.

I have tried  so many ways of getting the array from asyncData to render. I trying to return the data onto 'addons' so it fills out the form the same way my method does.

Here is my working method

```
async getAddons() {
      var addonsRef = db
        .collection('addons')
        .where('publish', '==', true)
        .orderBy('timeUpdated', 'desc');
      await addonsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const addons = {
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id
          };
          return this.addons.push(addons);
        });
      });
    },
```

And here is the code I am currently trying inside asyncData

```
async asyncData({ app, error }) {
    const addonsRef = await db
      .collection('addons')
      .where('publish', '==', true)
      .orderBy('timeUpdated', 'desc');
    try {
      await addonsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const addons = {
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id
          };
          return app.addons.push(addons);
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // TODO: error handling
      console.error(e);
    }
    return app.addons.push(addons);
  },
```

I expect the asyncData code to populate the array so it fills out my template the same as the getAddons function.

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: What result of app.addons.push(addons) and how u reference it in tempalte

Comment: I am getting an empty array according to a console.log The template is using {{addon.name}} and such.

Comment: so thats the problem. u are getting empty array. asyncDAta will be executed on server on initial page load

Comment: That's not a problem, that is what is expected. But is should be returning data that will prerender. I already have it working on view pages that do a single call and not ask for a collection.

Comment: Turns out the problem was user error. I was trying to use asyncData inside a component and not on a page. arg. Thanks for the help @aldarund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return dictionary from asyncData. E.g.

```
{
 something:  app.addons.push(addons)
}
```

And then in template you access it via `{{something. }}`

Comment: Tried that and I am still not getting anything back.